# How to deliver corruption reports?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I understand that you need to take corruption reports to an preparation system of your power. However, I have done so, yet no base is giving me the opportunity to hand them in. Have I missed something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Sjoerd it could be, but the guy who answered on reddit sounded pretty sure he knew what was up

Comment: The current answer is correct, given the current implementation. But it hasn't been this way in the past. So either it is an undocumented feature change, or it is bug introduced by a recent patch.

Comment: Oh right okay that makes more sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of Reddit user Arkhanist:

> We have very little CC this week to expand with, so preparation reports can only be delivered to very cheap systems that will ultimately cost us a lot of CC every week - some systems have been nominated, instead of delivering preparations. It's pretty much the same circumstance as when we're running a deficit and thus can't prepare any systems at all.
>   The best bet I'm afraid is to dispose of the preparation reports. You can dump them in open space (not near a station, or you'll get fined) - or if docked at a station, you can select them in your cargo bay on the right-hand view and dispose of them quickly that way.

So basically the power with which I am pledged (Lavigny) is running low on CC points this week so basically it cannot afford the reward for delivering corruption reports and as such, they are useless.

The best option in this situation is to dump them, either at a station or in deep space, and try again the week after when your power has more CC.

He also provided further information on powerplays in general:

[Lavigny's Legion "Welcome Pack"](https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteLavigny/wiki/welcome)

[In Depth Explanation of Powerplays](https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteLavigny/wiki/powerplay)

I hope this helps anyone else stuck in a similar situation.